# label text not display the correct value of user (string).. but messagebox.show show the value

Tags: c#, vb.net

im trying to show the value of **user** in the textbox1.text
but when i type

textbox1.text = user

**nothing show and the tool stop working**

im trying to change the value of textbox1.text via web response message

so the user is always changing and im trying to show it in textbox1.text

```
        Dim thlogin1 As Thread = New Thread(Sub() Login1(user, pass, target))
        thlogin1.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Login1(ByVal user As String, ByVal pass As String, ByVal target As String)

        Dim k As String
        k = user
        textbox.Text = k


    End Sub
```

Comment: Bit hard to know based on the code snippet, but something jumping out at me is you're creating an new thread, then updating the textbox text in this thread.  Honestly surprised why your not getting cross thread exceptions.  Perhaps you could explain exactly what you're attempting to do here with a bit more added context and we could suggest some alternatives

Comment: @Hursey thanks for your time mate..
this is a simple code i wrote 
this project linked with telegram bot..
so when a user send a message this message should be shown in textbox1.text ok?
but the project just ignore it or crush!
so when i tried  messagebox.show(user) it shows the message and everything runs fine!
so just want to know why the message dont show in textbox1.text if u can help me please and thanks for your time

Comment: Well, as I said.  The Textbox is being created on the main thread, your updating it on another thread, which means you're likely to have to do something along the lines of what RedneckSolutions suggested using Me.Invoke().  Your message box would of worked because it is being created in the same thread.  What I was really asking what exactly is the reason for the threading in the first place.

Comment: @Hursey and what you suggest me to do now 
im really tried everything and now i have no idea how to do it
i will be really appreciated for you

Comment: @Hursey can you please see the photo
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pBFw.png

Comment: What I suggest is explain what you are trying to achieve with the threading.  The reasoning is anything but clear when looking at your snippet.  If really all your doing is updating the textbox, there is not any reason to use threads

Comment: Re your screenshot, readup on the usage of Invoke, check out the usage RedneckSolutions suggested which is quite a bit different than yours

Comment: @Hursey 
see this photo of the error https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o7uP.png 
this thread i created just to start the login1 (start the tool)
is there anything wrong with it? 
i can change it if u suggest

Comment: @Hursey do you need another photo?

Comment: @Hursey its workeeeeeeeeeeeeeeed 
its worked you are a genius
OMMMMMG im really happy thankkkks you alooot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
textbox.Text = ("k")
```

To:

```
Me.Invoke(Sub()
          textbox.Text = k
          End Sub)
```

Comment: downvoted: explain why, not just a simple "do this" instruction

Comment: hey man thanks its worked great with your code